# Как использовать библиотеку QIWI в Python?

Tags: python, pip

Нашел данную библиотеку https://github.com/m0sia/pyQIWI, но неясно как её установить (и можно ли через pip?)

И что значат эти настройки:

```
user = "" #User Name
token = "" #Auth token. Unuqie for each auth device.
udid = "000000000000000"
```

Где указывать номер, а где пароль?

Либо может есть альтернатива, под задачу - сверять операции и находить нужную по сумме и комментарию. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В самом [репозитории](https://github.com/m0sia/pyQIWI) есть простой пример использования:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import QIWI
import time
import os

user = "" #User Name
token = "" #Auth token. Unuqie for each auth device.
udid = "000000000000000" 

q = QIWI.QIWI(user,token,udid)
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/Moscow'
time.tzset()

print q.GetBalance()

for transaction in q.GetIncome("hour"):
    print "Time: %s Amount: %s I
```

Для установки можно воспользоваться [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqiwi/0.2.0) (`pip install pyQIWI`) или просто из репозитория скопировать в свой проект файл [QIWI.py](https://github.com/m0sia/pyQIWI/blob/master/QIWI.py)

---

Вопросы относительно `user`, `token`, `udid` решаются через гугление API QIWI, но я не сдержал любопытство и посмотрел из чего состоит QIWI.py и увидел:

```
XML_REQUEST =  """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <request>
        <request-type>3</request-type>
        <extra name="client-software">Android v1.15.2 QIW</extra>
        <terminal-id>%s</terminal-id>
        <extra name="token">%s</extra>
        <extra name="udid">%s</extra>
        </request>
        """ % (self.user,self.token,self.udid)
```

т.е. `user` это `terminal-id`

Comment: спасибо! а что значит termilan-id? и где настройки логина/пароля?

Comment: @xoid сам не знаю, с QIWI не работал :) вам нужно будет найти документацию по QIWI, и скорее всего связаться с их техподдержкой. `pyQIWI` симулирует запросы API запросы. Если вы у вас есть сервис, который интегрирован с QIWI, то у вас наверное должны быть различные данные, типа токена